# Assembly: trying to write to file, but text is appending to filename

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to study assembly, while trying out the example in the tutorials I get stuck. I am compiling this using an ubuntu virtual machine.

Here is the code:

```
SYS_READ equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
SYS_OPEN equ 5
SYS_CLOSE equ 6
SYS_CREATE equ 8
SYS_EXIT equ 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, SYS_CREATE
    mov ebx, filename
    mov ecx, 0777
    int 0x80

    mov [fd_out],ebx

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov edx,len
    mov ecx,msg
    mov ebx,[fd_out]
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_CLOSE
    mov ebx,[fd_out]
    int 80h

    mov eax,SYS_OPEN
    mov ebx,filename
    mov ecx,0
    mov edx,0777
    int 0x80

    mov [fd_in],eax

    mov eax, SYS_READ
    mov ebx,[fd_in]
    mov ecx,info
    mov edx,26
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,info
    mov edx,26
    int 0x80

    mov eax,SYS_EXIT
    mov ebx,0
    int 0x80

section .data
    filename db 'test.txt'
    msg db 'Hello world file'
    len equ $-msg

section .bss
    fd_out resb 1
    fd_in resb 1
    info resb 26
```

after executing the compiled output, I get a file named **test.txtHello world file**.

Comment: `filename` is not null terminated. Use `filename db 'test.txt',0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While SYS_WRITE accepts the length of the information in EDX, the function SYS_CREATE needs a pointer to NULL terminated string for the filename.

Your filename, defined as

```
filename db 'test.txt'
```

is not NULL terminated and that is why it concatenates with the next string:

```
msg db 'Hello world file'
```

The terminating NULL in this case is the next defined:

```
fd_out resb 1
```

In order to fix it, simply define the filename with zero terminating byte:

```
filename db 'test.txt', 0
```

Comment: I got the name right but when I `cat` the file there is nothing there

Comment: @DominickNavarro That is because you store EBX in [fd_out], but SYS_CREAT returns the file descriptor in EAX. Notice also, that fd_out and fd_in must be defined as dword, not byte. It is strange how you was able to compile your code.

Comment: @DominickNavarro Another issue is that in NASM the octal numbers are encoded by "o" or "q" suffix or "0o" or "0q" prefix. So it should be "777q" or "777o" or "0o777" or "0q777". Not "0777" - it is decimal.

Comment: thank you for the note, I just found out this example from a tutorial website. I will be trying out your suggestions.